# Network Render recognizes both computers, sees the job, but is STUCK ON QUEUE

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, network

I am running 2.78 on two identical Macbook Pros. I've setup 1 to be the slave, one to be the master, and they seem to be connected and able to send jobs... however, when I try to start the render, it just remains stuck on "Queued" when I check on the Master Monitor.

I'll try to summarize what I've already troubleshooted:

- Both Slave and Master are on the same network with their TMP folders changed to both point to the same location (a folder stored on my Google Drive)
- I tried unchecking all of the "Tags" under Slave/Slave Settings on the master computer
- I've tried exporting my files as separate PNGs to be combined later, rather than exporting 1 Movie file.

No luck still. Anyone have help? :)

Comment: Offtopic rant: Never ever ever render animations directly from 3D into movie files, always to image sequences